# .NET Networking Crashes

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, network-programming

I'm attempting to use the System.Net.Sockets library in VB.Net to communicate with a web server, however everything I do results in an exception and crashes the application with no error. I have reason to believe that it is something with the schools network configuration.

I have tried the following, all of which resulting in an exception and a crash:

- Simple UDP client sending a packet
- DownloadString on a WebClient
- Using the Web Browser form element
- Resolving an IP from a given domain

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong with the network/.net config that could result in an error like this occuring?

Comment: _" an exception"_ Which one?  And what _actual code_ are you running that causes it?

Comment: What is "the System.Net.Sockets library"? You are supposed to use System.dll.